# Deserialise XML File to .Net Object

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize an xml file to a .NET object by doing something like:

```
CarCollection myCarCollection = null;
string path = "CarCollection.xml";

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CarCollection));

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
myCarCollection= (CarCollection)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```

Here is the xml file I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CarCollection>
  <Car ID="A">
    <CarType Make="Ford" Model="Focus" />
    <CarOwner Name="Tom">
      <Report Type="Service">
        <ReportList>
          <Date>20-08-2010</Date>
        </ReportList>
      </Report>
    </CarOwner>
  </Car>
  <Car ID="B">
    <CarType Make="Vauxhall " Model="Corsa" />
    <CarOwner Name="Joe">
      <Report Type="Service">
        <ReportList>
          <Date>10-10-2008</Date>
          <Date>10-10-2009</Date>
          <Date>10-10-2010</Date>          
        </ReportList>
     </Report>
      <Report Type="Accident">
        <ReportList>
         <Date>20-01-2011</Date>
        </ReportList>
      </Report>
    </CarOwner>
  </Car>
</CarCollection>
```

I've tried many things but can't seem to get it working.

Could anyone please help me how to do deserialize to a .NET object.

Here is the C# Objects

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("CarCollection")]
public class CarCollection
{
    [XmlArray("Car")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Car", typeof(Car))]
    public Car[] Cars { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class Car
{
    [XmlAttribute("Make")]
    public string CarMakeType { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Model")]
    public string CarModelType { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("CarOwner")]
    [XmlArrayItem("CarOwner", typeof(CarOwner))]
    public CarOwner[] CarOwners { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class CarOwner
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Report")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Report", typeof(Report))]
    public Report[] Reports { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class Report
{
    [XmlAttribute("Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Report")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Report", typeof(DateTime))]
    public DateTime[] Reports { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please post why it isn't working, errors and what not. Also post the code to the CarCollection class

Comment: Show us your definition of Car object please. Also, what is it doing wrong. Are any Exceptions thrown?

Comment: How have you created the CarCollection class? Is it derived from an XML schema? hand coded? something else?

Comment: You need to paste the code for `Car` and `CarCollection`

Comment: Another test is to create a CarCollection and Serialize it, check if it is compatible to the xml you are trying to Deserialize

Comment: try changing StreamReader to XmlReader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tangentially you might find some benefit in using [XSD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to generate XML from your classes.

Comment: I've tried that however. i get the following error:   Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'CarCollectionCarCarOwnerReportReportListDate[]' to 'CarCollectionCarCarOwnerReportReportListDate'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'CarCollectionCarCarOwnerReportReportListDate' to 'CarCollectionCarCarOwnerReportReportListDate[]'

Comment: I've found the issue I was having in using XSD. I've not resolved the issue using the tool. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear you're on the way -- sorry I've not been around to reply, busy times.

Answer (score 2):

I bet this is due to the date format.
the xmlns declaration is also missing.

The Felice suggestion is a good one. Try to produce the desired result with serializing, before trying to deserialize

Comment: I'm not sure how to serilize the object. So far i'm just getting null object.  The code will compile and run but I end up getting null cars object.

Answer (score 0):

[Read this page in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to verify your code.
The yellow note halfway down the page specifies what requirements must be met by collections.

Also: pass the Car type too, to the Serializer constructor.

**EDIT**
The Report and Car tags are not closed!

**EDIT**

Here is the output when serializing. Spot the differences there are many. The biggest problem is how you are serializing the arrays. Start using plurals (Cars, Owners) for collections that wil make it more readable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CarCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<Car>
    <Car Make="make">
        <CarOwner>
            <CarOwner Name="name1">
                <Report>
                    <Report Type="rtype">
                        <Report>
                            <Report>2011-01-25T15:22:52.703125+01:00</Report>
                        </Report>
                    </Report>
                </Report>
            </CarOwner>
        </CarOwner>
    </Car>
    <Car Make="make2">
        <CarOwner>
            <CarOwner Name="name3">
                <Report>
                    <Report Type="rtype">
                        <Report>
                            <Report>2011-01-25T15:22:52.703125+01:00</Report>
                        </Report>
                    </Report>
                </Report>
            </CarOwner>
        </CarOwner>
    </Car>
</Car>
```

Comment: vis a vis unclosed tags: that may have been because the OP misformatted the markdown; I attempted to fix that.